# Parse XML to JSON when i call API ( JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, json, xml, api

I would like to convert the result of an XML API into Json for this I use a function.

But I get a data.for each is not a function error.
Below are the data to be modified in JSON

Did I make a mistake somewhere? Thank you in advance.

```
fetch(url)
                .then((url) => url.text())
                .then((txtUrl) => {
                const xmlString = txtUrl;
                var data = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml');
                console.log(data);
                data = xmlToJson(data);
           
                const tbody = document.querySelector('#user-table tbody');
                
                tbody.innerHTML = '';
    
                
    
                data.forEach( (user) => {
                const entry = document.createElement('tr')
           
            entry.innerHTML = `

                <tr>
                    <td class="column1">${user.Sent}</td>
                    <td class="column2">${user.Bounced}</td>
                    <td class="column3">${user.Delivered}</td>
                    <td class="column3">${user.Opens}</td>
                    <td class="column3">${user.UniqueOpens}</td>
                    <td class="column3">${user.Clicks}</td>
                    <td class="column3">${user.UniqueClicks}</td>
                    <td class="column3">${user.Clickers}</td>
                    <td class="column3">${user.Complaints}</td>
                    <td class="column3">${user.Unsubscribes}</td>
                    <td class="column3">${user.Bcc}</td>
                </tr>
                `;
              
                tbody.appendChild(entry);
                    });
    }


<ApiResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Data>
    <Sent>27164</Sent>
    <Bounced>985</Bounced>
    <Delivered>26179</Delivered>
    <Opens>1582</Opens>
    <UniqueOpens>1180</UniqueOpens>
    <Clicks>76</Clicks>
    <UniqueClicks>69</UniqueClicks>
    <Clickers>61</Clickers>
    <Complaints>6</Complaints>
    <Unsubscribes>219</Unsubscribes>
</Data>
```

Comment: Nobody can see your XML or the transformed JSON version. How do you expect anybody to help?

Comment: Sorry for that, `<ApiResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Data>
        <Sent>27164</Sent>
        <Bounced>985</Bounced>
        <Delivered>26179</Delivered>
        <Opens>1582</Opens>
        <UniqueOpens>1180</UniqueOpens>
        <Clicks>76</Clicks>
        <UniqueClicks>69</UniqueClicks>
        <Clickers>61</Clickers>
        <Complaints>6</Complaints>
        <Unsubscribes>219</Unsubscribes>
    </Data>
</ApiResponse>`

Comment: Add the JSON converted version. The resulting JavaScript object is where the problem lies. The error means that the thing you expect to be an array is not an array.

Comment: That is just 1 item, not a list.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Sorry I'm new to JS

Comment: Its because data is a integer ?

Comment: it is becaus data is not an Array or a Collection. It can't be iterated over

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the DOM that you already built, no need for JSON here.  Use the object that you already have.

Here's a quick example of parsing the XML with XPath to build a table row and cells.

```
function getAPIResult(strURL) {
    let apiresult = document.querySelector("#apiresult tbody");
    if (apiresult == null) {
        return;
    }

    fetch(strURL)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok)
                return response.text();
            else 
                throw Error("Error: " + response.url + " " + response.status + " " + response.statusText);
        })
        .then(content => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(content, "text/xml"))
        .then(xml => {
            var ndList = xml.evaluate("//Data/*", xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
            while (ndElement = ndList.iterateNext()) {
                var ndRow = document.createElement("tr");
                var ndCell = document.createElement("td");
                ndCell.innerText = ndElement.textContent;
                ndRow.appendChild(ndCell);
                apiresult.appendChild(ndRow);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```